# Why kafka documentation says "stream of records"?

Tags: apache-kafka

Can somebody explain what does it mean as "stream of records" in the kafka documentation?

https://kafka.apache.org/intro

> Eg. The Producer API allows an application to publish a stream of
>   records to one or more Kafka topics.

I started my work in Kafka recently and I have been publishing/producing records to the kafka cluster but the records are pushed one by one. I'm not able to wrap around my head when I read "stream of records". I understand kafka helps in building streaming applications using kstreams and ksql but how producer API helps to push "stream of records"? Does this mean batching of records and pushed at once?

Answer (score 0):

A stream can be considered a consistent model of data over a period of time. Although you can produce  random data to a topic, the serializer and deserializer expect consistent types on both sides of the broker

Your question really isn't different than asking why `InputStream` and `OutputStream` are named such a way when they send bytes "one by one"

Comment: Let me go by your comment, is that expected to have consistent model in "InputStream"? IMHO, it is just a serious of bytes, and what I make out of it is up to me. Consistent model is maintained through API / Schema contracts not by the term "stream"

Comment: And what you put into a ProducerRecord is also just bytes